# Pushing pointers into c++ vectors, and cleanup

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks, vector, push-back

I am converting some code between different systems, and I have a question regarding c++ vectors.

If I do something like this:

In header file:

```
struct Vertex
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
}

struct submesh
{
    Vertex *meshdata;
}

std::vector<submesh> meshes;
```

In a routine in the c++ file:

```
{
    Vertex *data = new Vertex[1024];

    submesh g;
    g.meshdata = data;
    meshes.push_back(g);

    delete [] data;
}
```

Will I be in trouble? My assumption is that the vector would hold a pointer to data that is no longer valid once I called **delete** on it. Do I need to write a copy constructor for **Vertex** so that the data is copied first?

**Additional:**

The question was more to do with how do I put a pointer to allocated memory into a std::vector<> and still cleanup the locally allocated data. Essentially, how do I copy the data into the vector so I can still clean up my copy.

The original code was in DirectX. I am porting it to the iPhone. The original code allocated a submesh locally in a routine using:

```
{
    ID3DXMesh* subMesh = 0;
    D3DXCreateMesh(SubGrid::NUM_TRIS, SubGrid::NUM_VERTS, D3DXMESH_MANAGED, elems, gd3dDevice, &subMesh));

    //
    // ... do some magical things to submesh
    //

    SubGrid g;
    g.mesh = subMesh;
    g.box  = bndBox;
    mSubGrids.push_back(g);
}
```

I am trying to duplicate how ID3DXMesh is able to be added to a vector, then lose it's scope in the routine.

As I don't have access to D3DXCreateMesh(), I figured I would simply allocate the vertices I needed, throw them into a vector, and clean up.

Sorry, I wanted to keep the nitty gritty details out of it, as the question is simply how do I allocate a chunk of data, put a pointer into a std::vector<>, then clean up the locally allocated memory. :)

I assumed a copy constructor had to be written somewhere. Just wasn't sure where or how.

A subgrid looks like this:

```
struct SubGrid
{
    ID3DXMesh* mesh;
    AABB box;

    // For sorting.
    bool operator<(const SubGrid& rhs)const;

    const static int NUM_ROWS  = 33;
    const static int NUM_COLS  = 33;
    const static int NUM_TRIS  = (NUM_ROWS-1)*(NUM_COLS-1)*2;
    const static int NUM_VERTS = NUM_ROWS*NUM_COLS;
};
```

And the vector they get added to looks like:

```
std::vector<SubGrid> mSubGrids;
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're not just declaring a `std::vector<Vertex>` or `std::array<Vertex,1024>` in your `submesh` struct and letting the library do all the lifting for you?

Comment: I've added more information. I am trying to duplicate the behavior of one API to another. The initial code was just there to get to the idea across of what I was having an issue doing.

Comment: Your finishing question *almost* answers itself. *"How do I allocate a chunk of data, put a **pointer** into a std::vector<>, then clean up the locally allocated memory."* In short, you don't; not if you expect the now-container-homed object to *"own"* the memory. However, there are alternatives that may be better suited for what you need. When at all possible stick with an [RAII-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) solution, and it *is* possible in this case. If I have the time I'll try and spin up one for you.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions. Once again, stackoverflow proves to be a valuable resource. It sounds like std::vector<> will happily do all the memory cleanup itself if I do things properly. Although, I've never been a fan of allocating in one place, and trusting the deallocation is happening somewhere else. Goes against my OO way of thinking. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't directly dynamicly-allocate when you don't need to, and in this case you don't. Since you're filling your own submesh data rather than using `ID3DXMesh`, the container of that data should be RAII-compliant. If I were coding this I would remove the `submesh` class entirely and just use:

```
// vector containing list of vertices.
typedef std::vector<Vertex> SubMesh;
```

Your `SubGrid` class can then become a simple container that holds, as one of its properties, a `submesh` collection. I noticed you also have a class `AABB` for a box object. You would continue to keep that inside `SubGrid`. I don't have ton to work with here, so I'm making some of these up as I go along, but something like the following:

```
// a simple 3-value triplet of floats
struct Vertex
{
    float x,y,z;
};

// a Submesh is an arbitrary collection of Vertex objects.
typedef std::vector<Vertex> SubMesh;

// I'm defining AABB to be an 8-vertex object. your definition
//  is likely different, but I needed something to compile with =)
typedef Vertex AABB[8];

class SubGrid
{
public:
    SubGrid() {};

    // comparator for container ordering
    bool operator <(const SubGrid&);

    // submesh accessors
    void setSubmesh(const SubMesh& mesh) { submesh = mesh;}
    SubMesh& getSubmesh() { return submesh; }
    const SubMesh& getSubmesh() const { return submesh; }

    // box accessors
    AABB& getBox() { return box; }
    const AABB& getBox() const { return box;}

private:
    SubMesh submesh;
    AABB box;
};

// arbitrary collection of SubGrid objects
typedef std::vector<SubGrid> SubGrids;
```

When adding this to your global `SubGrid` collection `g`, you have several possibilities. You could just do this:

```
// declared globally 
Subgrids g;

// in some function for adding a subgrid item
SubGrid subgrid;
AABB& box = subgrid.getBox();
SubBesh& submesh = subgrid.getSubmesh();

// ... initialize your box and submesh data ...

g.push_back(subgrid);
```

But you'd be copying a lot of data around. To tighten up the memory access you could always do this instead:

```
// push an empty SubGrid first, then set it up in-place
g.push_back(SubGrid());
Subgrid& subgrid = *(g.back());
AABB& box = subgrid.getBox();
SubMesh& submesh = subgrid.getSubmesh();

//... initialize your box and submesh data ...
```

This will establish a reference to the `SubGrid` just added to the global collection, then allow you to modify it in-place. This is but-one of a number of possible setup options. It should be noted that if you have C++11 in your toolchain (and if you're doing this on MacOS or iOS, you likely do, as Apple LLVM 4.2's clang is pretty good on C++11 compliance) this can get even more efficient with judicious usage of **move-constructors** and **move-assignment-operators**.

Most importantly, not a `new` or `delete` to be seen.

Anyway, I hope this gives you some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course, vector will have a pointer to deleted memory. What you need is either:

1. Create copy constructor for `submesh` (not `Vertex`).OR
2. Change`submesh` to have array of Vertex (not just a pointer).

Copy constructor can be done like this:

```
struct submesh
{
    Vertex *meshdata;
    unsigned meshsize;
    submesh(Vertex* v = 0, unsigned s= 0) : meshdata(v), meshsize(s){}
    submesh(const submesh& s)
    {
        if(meshdata) /*we have stored data, delete it.*/ delete(meshdata);
        meshdata = new Vertex[s.meshsize];
        meshsize = s.meshsize;
        memcpy(meshdata, s.meshdata, sizeof(Vertex) * meshsize);
    }
};
```

For sure it is much recommended to use  [unique_ptr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/) (if you use c++11) or [auto_ptr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/auto_ptr/) for old c++. To avoid the nightmare of memory management as much as you can.

Check [How to avoid memory leaks when using a vector of pointers to dynamically allocated objects in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361139/c-vector-pointers-to-objects)

Comment: I like the idea of creating the copy constructor. The array of vertices wouldn't work as it could be a variable number of them.

I will research copy constructors right now. Would you happen to have an example of how one would be written handy?

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine in single threaded application. Your code only allocate `data` memory once and `delete [] data` once.

> Do I need to write a copy constructor for Vertex so that the data is copied first?

Your code is clean as you shown, `meshes` points to only allocated `data`. If you meant to copy `data` when call `meshes.push_back(g)`, then your code doesn't do what you meant to.

You might want to use `std::vector` instead:

```
struct submesh
{
    std::vector<Vertex> meshdata;
}

vector<submesh> meshes;

void Func()
{
    meshes.emplace_back(submesh());
    meshes.at(0).meshdata.resize(100);
}
```

STL container uses [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) idiom, it manages memory deallocation for you automatically.

Comment: Yes sorry. The code is using std::vector<Vertex>. It was 3am when I posted and I was typing from memory. :)