# c++ vectors of abstract classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, polymorphism

I'm trying to make a c++ variable  of `vector<Superclass>`.

I originally gave the `Superclass` a public function in the header: `virtual int function();` that I attempted to override in two subclasses like such:

--in the header--

`class Subclassthing : public Superclass {
 public: int function(); ...}`

--in the cpp file--

`int Subclass::function() {//actually do stuff}`

I later create a `vector<Superclass>` that I add `Subclass` elements into and call function() on.

The build screamed at me for some insane reason that led me to some hex codes when I tried to see why. It got stopped breaking when I instead changed the declaration in the superclass to `virtual int function() {return 0;}` , but I suspect that I'm not doing this properly and that it will only call the Superclass's version as opposed to the subclass's. How do I fix this? At first I tried to make the superclass declaration a pure virtual function but then I was no longer able to create a vector of it, since I can't instantiate pure virtual objects.

**edit:** ok I realize I'm getting screwed by slicing now. does this mean that there's no way to do this elegantly (er, without pointers?)

Comment: Yes you need to use pointers. You could however use boost's shared_ptr, or c++11's unique_ptr/shared_ptr

Comment: The first answer on this question goes into it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361139/c-vector-of-pointers-to-objects

Comment: thanks, the suggested duplicate wasn't as helpful :)

Comment: Sorry I was the one who suggested that duplicate :P and found the second later :)